# NoSQL database that is with ACID properties and support transaction management

Tags: nosql, acid

I am new to NoSQL and want to find a NoSQL database that is with ACID properties and support transaction management for a payment service. Is there any NoSQL database which supports these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a recent [MongoDB blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb), we can see that MongoDB as of major release 4.0 supports ACID:

> MongoDB 4.0 will add support for multi-document transactions, making it the only database to combine the speed, flexibility, and power of the document model with ACID data integrity guarantees. Through snapshot isolation, transactions provide a globally consistent view of data, and enforce all-or-nothing execution to maintain data integrity.

If you happen to be using Spring, all you would have to do to make a method ACID compliant would be to annotate it with `@Transactional`.  The framework and Mongo would automatically handle the rest.